# Show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i/\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 = 1$ for Bernoulli distributed random variables $Y_i$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I want to show that:
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2} = 1$ almost surely given that $(Y_n)$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables, $P(Y_i = 0) = a, P(Y_i = 1) = 1-a$.

I am confused about this 'almost surely'. What is a sequence of random variables?
I guess somehow I can maybe convert the sum into a product and then use the independence...Any hints?

Edit: found out that 'almost 'surely' means that the probability of it is 1. Also, in our case we actually just have an IID.

Comment: At a minimum, you should look up, and understand, the definitions of the terms in your problem before asking for a solution.

Comment: Can you tell me what's the distribution of $Y_i$ and $Y_i^2$? 
I.e. I'm asking what values do they take with what probability.

Comment: If $Y$ takes only values 0 and 1, then $Y$ and $Y^2$ have the same distribution.

Comment: This is an application of the (strong) "Law of Large Numbers" (LLN).

Comment: @Michael Actuallt this is **not** "an application of the (strong) "Law of Large Numbers" (LLN)".

Comment: @BruceET Even more than that, Y and Y^2 are *equal* then.

Comment: Yes, it is an application of strong LLN (this and more general problems like it can be solved that way), though I suppose in this special case of Bernoulli random variables you can evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2}$ even more simply.  There seems to be more educational value in learning to apply LLN, so I am guessing this particular special case was accidental, a better-designed question would have $\{Y_i\}$ i.i.d. with $E[Y_i^2]\neq 0$.

Comment: If I wanted to use the LLN, how can I do? @Michael

Comment: Note that $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is i.i.d., and also $\{Y_i^2\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is i.i.d. Now, do you know the statement of the LLN?

Comment: As far as I understand: I have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, for example $(Y_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ AND this sequence has a finite expected value $E(Y_i) = \mu$. Then almost surely $\frac{Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 + ... + Y_n}{n}$ converges to $\mu$.

Comment: @Michael Two questions: 1. Do you understand the notion of overkill? 2. Are you opposed to the use of @?

Comment: @今天春天 : Yes, so, can you find a way to massage the expression $\frac{Y_1 + Y_2 + ... + Y_n}{Y_1^2 + Y_2^2 + ... + Y_n^2}$ to get the form you want to apply LLN?

Comment: @Did : Again, there seems to be more educational value in learning to apply LLN, and indeed that is what the asker seems interested in.  For example, what if the asker has an upcoming test that asks to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i^3}$ for $\{Y_i\}$ i.i.d. with $P[Y=0]=P[Y=1]=P[Y=2]=1/3$?  Your special case of Bernoulli random variables will not help very much.

Comment: @Michael More exactly, the OP seems quite happy with the natural answer they accepted (based ont actually reading the question and noting that Y=Y^2 hence every ratio is identically 1 as soon as the sum is not 0), plus an additional remark explaining how to apply the overkill. (Congrats for using @.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Y_i$ takes only the values $0$ and $1$, we have $Y_i^2 = Y_i$ for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $$\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i.$$ For any $\omega \in \Omega$ we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2(\omega)>0$. Thus, $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(\omega)}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2(\omega)} = 1$$ for all $n \geq N$. In particular, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(\omega)}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2(\omega)} = 1.$$

Comment: But what about the probability of the random variables? And will there always be a $N$?

Comment: What does the fact say us that $P(Y_i=0)=a$ and $P(Y_i=1)= 1-a$?

Comment: @今天春天 We have $\sum_{i \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(Y_i=1) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a) = \infty$ and therefore it follows from the Borel Cantelli lemma that for each $\omega$ we can find large $N$ such that $Y_N(\omega)=1$.

Comment: Maybe the Borel Cantelli lemma should be part of the proof in some way.

Comment: @今天春天 It is... as i just told you in my previous comment.

Comment: @saz : Good observation about this special Bernoulli case.  Of course I suppose we need $a \neq 1$.

Comment: Last question: how is that related to the LLN?

Comment: @今天春天 Well, there is no need for LLN here. It is possible to apply LLN to obtain the result, but this is kind of overkill.